# Performance counters collection - Linux

Tags: linux, intel, perfmon

```
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
perf version 3.2.33
python 2.7
OS: Linux. Distro: Ubuntu 12.10
```

I am trying to collect, PerThread performance counters using perfmon.
these are the events that I am trying to collect: `perf_events=['INSTRUCTIONS_RETIRED','L2_LINES_IN','LLC_MISSES']`

I am able to collect the data at times - `unpredictable.` 
Sometimes, I am able to collect the data. 
I am trying to run the `PARSEC - CANNEAL Benchmark thread.`

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 44, in apport_excepthook
```

This is the error, I keep getting sometimes. I tried googling about scenario's, if people had this kind of issue
Google keywords: `"perfmon perthread session traces unpredictable"` | `perfmon events collection intel unpredictable`

I could also post snippets of the code, if necessary.

One more interesting thing I notice is, if I run the same thread twice, without killing the previous thread. I am able to collect it everytime. 
Does that mean anychance mean? that I don't have enough IPS to report in the first instance? that can't be the case, because - the `"top"`shows that the core is at 100%
Thanks

Comment: Can you try `perf` tool? It is included in the Ubuntu ("sudo apt-get install linux-tools"), there is a tutorial: https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial

Comment: I have to use perfmon because it provides PerThreadSessions - which will be used later. I have tried with "perf" it works fine.

Was wondering why this error would occur.